# Django with docker compose can not open file '/code/manage.py

Tags: django, docker

i am deploying to docker compose django with postgrest but the problem i have is when trying to deploy an app to django as i get the following output.

> [+] Running 1/0  ⠿ Container proyecto-db-1  Running
> 0.0s python: can't open file '/code/manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
> asterisk@localhost:~/Documentos/Programacion/django/Proyecto>

I get this output by implementing the following code:

> docker compose run web python manage.py startapp aplicacion

> docker compose run web django-admin startproject proyecto

the docker-compose.yml is:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_NAME=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    depends_on:
      - db
```

The Dockerfile is:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code/
```

requirements.txt:

```
Django>=3.0,<4.0
djangorestframework==3.13.1
psycopg2>=2.8
```

and .env is:

```
## do not put this file under version control!
SECRET_KEY='c_r-e8v1divj8y+hu@-w=n#$xj#ciuejybd3_(k2h789(mcv8$'
DEBUG=False

## Super-User Credentials
SUPER_USER_NAME = 'root'
SUPER_USER_PASSWORD = 'root'
SUPER_USER_EMAIL = 'admin@email.com'
```

There is the manage.py file

[image]

Comment: Try: `python ./<directory_in_which_manage_py_is_located>/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`. The Dockerfile and manage.py are not on the same level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your docker image root and manage.py are not in the same directory. The image root is one level above.

Try: `python ./<directory_in_which_manage_py_is_located>/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` in your `docker-compose.yml` file.

Answer (score 0):

Docker image is trying to find the `manage.py` file in root directory and your `manage.py` resides in `proyecto` directory.

In `docker-compose.yml`

```html
version: '3.9'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    working_dir: proyecto
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_NAME=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    depends_on:
      - db
```